# Use of "will" vs "would"

Tags: modal-verbs, modality, will-would

"You have used a cumbersome method to solve this question.I **would not / will not** use it."

Which of above two(would and will) is preferrable to use?
Can **would not** be used above to politely refuse?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but mean different things.

1) I **will not** use it.

expresses the speaker's determination not to use the method his/her interlocutor has used.

2) I **would not** use it.

can express the same idea as (1), though in a less categorical form. However, in this context in which the interlocutor's attitude has been described, it will most likely mean:

2') I **would not** use it **if I were you**.

Therefore, (2) expresses criticism about the interlocutor's use of the method and the speaker's hypothetical adoption of a different approach.

Comment: Is "would not" not used for politely refusing anything?Is it used only to express hypothetical situation?

Comment: Not in this case. I see it as hypothetical.

Comment: may you give example when 'would' not is used for politely refusing anything?

Comment: I can only imagine that in reply to a question with *would*: A. Would you  use the same method? B. No, I wouldn't.